# How to add £ to valueBox output

Tags: r, shiny

How do I add currency to my valueBox, £ in this case.

The valueBox generated in the server as:

```
valueBox(Test_data %>%
         filter(`Region` == input$Region, `Locality` == input$Locality) %>%
         summarise("Annual_Value" = sum(`Value (Annualised)`)) %>%
         prettyNum(big.mark = ","),
             
             req(input$Region))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just went into the windows explorer and found "Character Map".  From there I was able to copy paste the symbol into R.  Since you didn't provide a reprex, here's a simple response.  Basically, calculate the value you need, feed it into paste for the `value` in the `valueBox`.

```
calc_value <- 200

valueBox(value = paste('£', calc_value), subtitle = '')
```

[image]